# Jquery Ajax uploading big file gives error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, iis

I'm using [this](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) to crop images on the admin panel I'm working on. This plugin will give you the cropped image as base64 string and I'll send that string to server as it is and then convert it to image on server, this works fine as I use average size images(the biggest I've tried successfully was 880KB) but then I tried an 7MB image and around 15%~20% of its progress the request gives 404 error.

I'm using c# and I've made the below changes:

```
<httpRuntime
  executionTimeout="9999999"
  maxRequestLength="1048576"
  targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

and

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

but still the same error occurs. what could be the possible reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And this is a post request, right? Why not just send the image as a file.

Comment: @adeneo yea it's a post request, the image is being send along side with some other information. the out put image is string, how can I send it via ajax as a file?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, it sounds really strange that the server would suddenly send a 404 after first uploading 20%? Must be a server issue.

Comment: @adeneo Well I figured it out, since the plugin I'm using gives me the cropped image as base64 string, the string will be quiet BIG comparing to the image size itself so by increasing the maxAllowedContentLength it was fixed. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since the plugin I'm using for cropping gives me the base64 string of the cropped image and it's quiet BIG text, increasing the maxAllowedContentLength fixed the issue.

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```